Proof for limit of composite function
I have been trying to prove the following theorem
Given
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$$
$$\lim_{y \to b}g(y)=a$$
If $f$ is continuous a $a$ or $g(y) \neq a$ except possibly when $y=b$. Then
$$\lim_{x \to b}f(g(x))=L$$
I cannot account for why the secondary conditions are necessary, can someone point out the issue in my proof:
Since $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$, given a $\epsilon > 0$ we may find a $\delta > 0$ such that
$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ when $|x-a|<\delta$.
Now let $x=g(y)$.
It follows that $|f(g(y))-L|<\epsilon$ when $|g(y)-a|<\delta$.
But since $\lim_{y \to b}g(y)=a$, We may find a $\Delta > 0$ such that $|g(y)-a|<\delta$ when $|y-b| < \Delta$
Hence for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\Delta$ such that  $|f(g(y))-L|<\epsilon$ when $|y-b| < \Delta$.

The error is with the line “It follows that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ when $|g(y) - a| < \delta$.” This only holds if $f$ is continuous. Using only the definition of a limit, it should read that $0 <|g(y) - a| < \delta$. This is why the second condition is necessary, since it eliminates the possibility of the term equaling zero. A simple example like $g(y) = 0$ and $f(x)$ having a point discontinuity at $0$ will make it more apparent what can go wrong.
